# Why does request.getCookies() return null when no cookies have been sent?

Tags: java, servlets

According to the [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getCookies%28%29), `HttpServletRequest.getCookies()` "Returns an array containing all of the Cookie objects the client sent with this request.", and it returns `null` if no cookies were sent.

Is there a specific reason for this behavior other than returning an empty array, which seems a little more intuitive to me and avoids needing to check for null before iterating on the array to look for a specific cookie?

Comment: File.list() does similar - returns null if not a directory or I/O error occurs - very annoying.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That used to be a common Java practice in situations like this. The main reason was probably due to it being slightly more efficient to return nothing than return an empty list (less work on the garbage collector).

Comment: That makes sense, but shouldn't it be viable to have a static empty array in the class returning null and to return it instead of null? I don't know how the GC behaves in these cases, but my guess is that the static variable would be accessed by reference and wouldn't need to be GC'ed...or am I wrong?

Comment: You are not wrong, what I can think about is that this situation is a result of a "common practice" (even in javascript we can find similar behaviours) like Mike just wrote.